# $stateChangeSuccess getting fired after controller is instantiated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Route configuration:

```
        $stateProvider.state('root', {
            url: "/",
            template: '<div ui-view></div>'
          })
      .state('root.child',{
         url: '/child',
         templateUrl: 'some.html'
         controller: function(){
             console.log('child')
         }
      });
```

StateChangeStart listener:

```
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, state, params, fromState, fromParams) {
         console.log('state change start');
            }
        });
```

When I navigate to state 'root.child', first 'state change start' is printed on console and then 'child' is printed.
But when I refresh the page while in child state or directly hit the url '/child', first 'child' is printed and then 'state change start' is printed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `event.preventDefault();` first.

For your interest, if you want to do something where you run `$state` within the `$stateChangeStart`, it will not work. It's a known issue.